# How to link Facebook mobile ad campaign to a user?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, ads, attribution

We are using Facebook mobile ad campaigns to let users install install our app via the App Store and Play Store.
However, currently we don't have a way of tracking "how" a user reached our app. i.e. which specific ad campaign they came from when installing the app.

Largely, this is because FB mobile ad campaigns don't have support for UTM tags.

I know there are 3rd party solutions that helps with attribution, such as adjust and AppsFlyer. However, I'd like to know if this is possible using just the FB ads SDK for Android and iOS.

Thanks in advance!